# What was the study that shows peoples' tax preferences shift when they get more information about their income?

Tags: reference-request, preferences, taxation, experimental-economics

I am trying to find a study I read a few years ago, but I forgot the names of the authors and the title of the study. I have already tried to search for the study on Google Scholar without much luck. However, the study was highly publicized at the time. I remember learning about it from Marginal Revolution, and I think it was even mentioned in The Economist. So, my hope is that someone might remember the study.

What I know about the study:

- It was an experiment where people were asked to report their political preferences on taxes and transfers twice: once before they were given information about where they stand in the income (or possibly wealth) distribution, and once after.
- The study's results indicated that once people learned where they stood in the income distribution, their preferences shifted towards lower taxes and less redistribution.
- I know the study had to have been conducted after 2009 because it's not possible that I read it before that, I wasn't interested in economics before then.
- I think the study was conducted in one of the Scandinavian countries. I'm not entirely sure anymore, but I remember it was some developed country in northern Europe or America.

Does anyone know which study this could be?